# Loop through column and update it with MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to loop through some records and update them with an ad hoc query in MySql. I have a name field, so I just want to loop though all of them and append a counter to each name, so it will be name1, name2, name3.  Most examples I see use stored procs, but I don't need a stored proc.

Answer (score 3):

As a stepping stone on your way to developing an UPDATE statement, first generate a SELECT statement that generates the new `name` values to your liking. For example:

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.name
     , CONCAT(t.name,s.seq) AS new_name
  FROM ( SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS seq
              , m.id
           FROM mytable m
           JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) i
          ORDER BY m.id
       ) s
  JOIN mytable t
    ON t.id = s.id
 ORDER BY t.id
```

To unpack that a bit... the `@i` is a MySQL user variable. We use an inline view (aliased as i) to initialize `@i` to a value of 0. This inline view is joined to the table to be updated, and each row gets assigned an ascending integer value (aliased as `seq`) 1,2,3...

We also retrieve a primary (or unique) key value, so that we can match each of the rows from the inline view (one-to-one) to the table to be updated.

It's important that you understand how that statement is working, before you attempt writing an UPDATE statement following the same pattern.

We can now use that SELECT statement as an inline view in an UPDATE statement, for example:

```
UPDATE ( SELECT t.id
              , t.name
              , CONCAT(t.name,s.seq) AS new_name
           FROM ( SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS seq
                       , m.id
                    FROM mytable m
                    JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) i
                   ORDER BY m.id
                ) s
           JOIN mytable t
             ON t.id = s.id
          ORDER BY t.id
       ) r
  JOIN mytable u
    ON u.id = r.id
   SET u.name = r.new_name
```

SQL Fiddle demonstration here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8796/1

I had to extrapolate, and provide a table name (`mytable`) and a column name for a primary key column (`id`).

In the SQL Fiddle, there's a second table, named prodtable which is identical to mytable. SQL Fiddle only allows SELECT in the query pane, so in order to demonstrate BOTH the SELECT and the UPDATE, I needed two identical tables.

*CAVEAT*: be VERY careful in using MySQL user variables. I typically use them only in SELECT statements, where the behavior is very consistent, with careful coding. With DML statements, it gets more dicey. The behavior may not be as consistent in DML, the "trick" is to use a SELECT statement as an inline view. MySQL (v5.1 and v5.5) will process the query for the inline view and materialize the resultset as a temporary MyISAM table.

I have successfully used this technique to assign values in an `UPDATE` statement. But (IMPORTANT NOTE) the MySQL documentation does NOT specify that this usage or MySQL user variables is supported, or guaranteed, or that this behavior will not change in a future release.

Comment: I don't want to update another able though. I want to update the existing records in a single table.

Comment: The example `UPDATE` statement I provided above does in fact "update the existing records in a single table". Absent a table name and column names, I extrapolated and provided an example.

Comment: name and new_name contain the same data when I run the select: `name012345678....`.

Comment: I finally got it to work, but is it possible to make it generate `name, name1, name2, name3, name4`, instead of `name2, name3, name4, name5`

Comment: I got the above to work, I just started the @i variable at -2 and to make sure I don't get name0, I do a case on the s.seq. But now I have another issue which you probably know how to solve. In my table, I want the value name to go something like `name,name1,name2,name3`, but if it encounters another set of values such as test, it should start the sequence over and go `test,test1,test2,test3`.  Right now I have to put a where clause in the statement, but I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: @Xaisoft: those requirements are SIGNIFICANTLY different than the specifications in the original question. You might want to ask this in a different question, and ALSO provide an example that has more than one "set" of values (name and test) and an example of what you expect to be generated. Providing a specification would go a long ways towards you getting some help.

Answer (score 0):

Have the names stored in a table. Do a join against the names and update in the second table you want to.

Thanks